# Visual Studio: copy all needed dlls in the project output folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have several `C++/C#` projects in a Visual Studio solution file `MyProjects.sln`.

Most of them are related to the main project that I am working on, `BigProject`.

But this `BigProject` calls a separate executable that we can call `SideProject.exe` whose project  is in the same solution file.

Since `SideProject` dependencies may conflict with `BigProject` and I can have some DLLs mismatch I put the output of `SideProject` in `$(BigProjectOutputFolder)/SideProject/`

Now, `SideProject` may depend, directly or indirectly from other projects (`LittleProject1`, `LittleProject2`, etc.).

What is the best way to have all `SideProject` needed DLLs on its output folder?

I tried several attempts with little or no avail.

The only semi-working solution was to use the `xcopy` command as a `post-build event`, but it does not automatially update itself if I add a new dependency so I may have disalignment issues.

I don't want to copy every `BigProject` dll in `SideProject` output folder since I can have version mismatch or copy DLLs that I don't need.

I tried with `<CopyLocal>True</CopyLocal>`, `<Private>True</Private>` in the `vcxproj` file but they didn't copy anything at all.

Any ideas?